# What's up with Archbishop Desmond?

Tags: credits, top-gear

In the Top Gear Botswana Special (series 10, episode 4), the credits look like this:

[image: Archbishop Desmond Clarkson, Archbishop Desmond Hammond, Archbishop Desmond May, Archbishop Desmond Stig, etc.]

> Presented by
>   Archbishop Desmond Clarkson
>   Archbishop Desmond Hammond
>   Archbishop Desmond May
>   and
>   Archbishop Desmond Stig
>
> Film Camera
>   Archbishop Desmond Harvey
>   Archbishop Desmond May
>   Archbishop Desmond Leaver
>   Archbishop Desmond Kennedy

Etcetera, etcetera. Everybody's name has turned into Archbischop Desmond name.

What's the story behind it?

It's probably a reference to activist, Nobel Prize winner and Archbishop [Desmond Tutu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desmond_Tutu). But while that man has achieved a great deal, he wasn't from Botswana. He studied at a university named after Botswana (but based in Lesotho AFAIK, not in Botswana itself), so I don't see a direct link.

[Top Gear's wikia](http://topgear.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_List#Series_Ten) doesn't have an entry on it.

Comment: This joke was also (perhaps first) used sometimes in *Monty Python's Flying Circus*.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe this is due to what TV Tropes calls a "Small Reference Pool" - pop culture's understanding of a topic only goes so far. *Top Gear* always uses these gag credits during its foreign specials, using either the names of famous people from that region, or a name commonly associated with that region ("Billy Bob", during the infamous USA special).

But how many world-famous Botswanans can you think of? I'm sure there *are* famous Botswanans, and I mean no offence to the country, but I can't think of any. It's likely the producers also couldn't think of one, or at least one that the general public would recognise, so instead they went with a guy who, while not quite Botswanan, *is* world-famous and has a distinctive name. The joke simply wouldn't have worked otherwise.

Comment: Precious Ramotswe?

Comment: @RupertMorrish As far as I'm concerned, a fictional Botswanan character is not much of a step up from a real person that's somewhat tied to Bostwana.

Comment: Not entirely sure the joke "worked" this way either. Unless it was *trying* to be ignorant, chauvinist and offensive, in which case it worked fine.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desmond_Tutu  (I know, I know), Desmond Tutu was born "of mixed Xhosa and Motswana heritage"  So in this instance Tutu has been co-opted into a lame gag in the same way that an English footballer with an Irish grandparent can be selected for the Irish team